# How to compare two conditons on a single line in a better way

Tags: c#, dictionary, boolean, comparison, equality-operator

Can this be done better?

```
private bool IsEntityNeeded(EntityType type) => EntitiesRequiredToBuildComposite.Contains(type) && !RequirementsObtainedDict.ContainsKey(type);
```

`RequirementsObtainedDict` is a `Dictionary<EntityType, AbstractEntity>`
`EntitiesRequiredToBuildComposite` is a `List<EntityType>`

I want to return a boolean if both conditions are true, and it has to be on one line of code.

I am aware I can take the comparison and create a function to do it and then call said function, but that would create more lines of code and is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Side note: "RequirementsObtained**List** is a Dictionary" not the best naming idea

Comment: EntitiesRequiredToBuildComposite would probably be better/faster as a HashSet

Answer (score 1):

Hi i think you might be looking for "coalescing".

https://csharp.today/c-6-features-null-conditional-and-and-null-coalescing-operators/

Comment: Good thinking! But I do not need to null check - and I cannot find a way to compact my method in performance or space using this.